# Intercepting Camel @Consume

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, aop, spring-aop

I have an existing application which is using Apache Camel to send messages to SEDA endpoints for Async processing and would like to intercept calls to these methods for instrumentation.

Example code:

```java
@Component
public class CamelMessageService {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CamelMessageService.class);

    public static final String QUEUE = "seda:message";

    @Resource
    private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

    public void send() {
        producerTemplate.sendBody(QUEUE, "Hello World");
    }

    @Consume(uri = QUEUE)
    public void receive(@Body String payload) {
        log.info("Received message {}", payload);
    }

}
```

Is there a way to intercept all methods annotated with `@Consume` before invoking. I looked at an AOP based approach but this seemed to fall over due to existing Spring/Camel proxying of these classes.

I have also tried using various Camel Intercept routes and adding a custom InterceptStrategy but it seems that the example above does not create a Camel route so is not intercepted.

**EDIT**: On further investigation in seems that these endpoints can be Intercepted using camel but only if there is at least 1 other route defined in the Camel Context?

```java
@Component
class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyRouteBuilder.class);

    public void configure() {
        interceptSendToEndpoint(CamelMessageService.QUEUE)
            .process(exchange -> log.info("intercepted exchange {}", exchange));

        from("timer:hello?period={{timer.period}}").routeId("hello").routeGroup("hello-group")
                .transform().simple("yo")
                .filter(simple("${body} contains 'foo'"))
                .to("log:foo")
                .end()
                .to("stream:out");
    }
}
```

If I run this app with the Route Builder above then my interceptor is triggered if however I comment out the `hello` route it is not?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can try to use plain AspectJ?

Comment: In order to reproduce your described problem with Spring proxies it would be good if you posted a little [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub. If users here have something they can compile and run, it will get much easier to help you. It is difficult to reason about something we cannot see. Please add the aspect you were trying to implement to the MCVE, too.